# Drupal Runtime error... RuntimeException: Guzzle requires cURL, the allow_url_fopen ini setting, or a custom HTTP handler

Tags: 14.04, drupal

I installed cURL on my 14.04 server but this is still happening... The Drupal installation went beautifully (no errors), but now whenever I try to click on a configuration link in the admin panel it goes to this page. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
RuntimeException: Guzzle requires cURL, the allow_url_fopen ini setting, or a custom HTTP handler. in GuzzleHttp\Client::getDefaultHandler() (line 125 of core/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php).

GuzzleHttp\Client->__construct(Array)
Drupal\Core\Http\Client->__construct()
Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Container\prod\service_container_prod->getHttpClientService()
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('http_client')
Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Container\prod\service_container_prod->getUpdate_FetcherService()
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('update.fetcher')
Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Container\prod\service_container_prod->getUpdate_ProcessorService()
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('update.processor')
Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Container\prod\service_container_prod->getUpdate_ManagerService()
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('update.manager')
Drupal::service('update.manager')
update_get_available()
update_requirements('runtime')
update_page_top(Array)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->buildPageTopAndBottom(Array)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, 'kernel.view', Object)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', Object)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object)

The website has encountered an error. Please try again later.
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `sudo apt-get install php-guzzle` fixes this. Just posting for others.